# How do you boot a computer that hangs on keyboard input?

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have an older Toshiba laptop. I've always known that it would hang on the Windows resume menu, but I never thought about it much until now. My sister tried to turn it on the other day, but decided that it was taking too long to start up, so she holds the power button and tries to turn it on again. That's where the issue starts.

Previously when you started it up, you would get the option to resume or boot into safe mode (it shut down a lot due to overheating), but it wasn't a big deal because you could let a timer expire and boot into Windows, where everything works. Now it boots to the startup repair screen, because Windows didn't finish starting up. This screen doesn't have a timer, and I can't select anything because keyboard input hangs the computer.

Is there a way to change a file with something such as a Linux live CD to force the computer to skip the startup repair menu?

Comment: Borrow/buy a USB keyboard to do the pre-boot stuff.

Comment: I have a Logitech USB keyboard, but that doesn't work either. It still hangs.

Comment: I don't suppose this laptop is old enough to have a PS/2 port? If so, you could try a PS/2 keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried booting from the installation disk (or system recovery disk)? That should work and let you repair your installation.